# Collapse all file code on 1 line

Tags: netbeans, coding-style, textmate, code-folding

Is there anyway way to collapse text all on 1 line with TextMate or Netbeans IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like visually collapse (why would you do that?) or in the sense of "remove linebreaks"? For the latter case, search for "`\n`" and replace with "", make sure "Regular expression" is checked.

Comment: i mean not to collapse for working on, i want to make the script smaller (minified) removing spacing and putting all in 1 line :P

Comment: Well, careful with that. Depending on the language, you NEED to retain some linebreaks, e.g. after single-line comments (`// comment`).